# Testing Interactive Queries in Kafka Streams

Tags: unit-testing, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I have a function which takes an instance of Kafka streams, gets the state store, parses it and do some computation.

```
void func1(KafkaStreams streams)
{
   StoreQueryParameters<ReadOnlyKeyValueStore<String, Long>> storeQueryParams = 
                StoreQueryParameters.fromNameAndType(...);
   ReadOnlyKeyValueStore<String, Long> stateStore = streams.store(storeQueryParams);
   KeyValueIterator<String, Long> range = stateStore.all();
   ...
   // using this iterator, I will read each record in state store and do some computation.
}
```

Let's assume the topology for the Kafka streams a simple one, where we read from a topic and store the exact records in the state store.

How to test these kinds of functions, which requires Kafka setup?

Answer (score 4):

You can try to test the store directly, via [`TopologyTestDriver`](https://www.confluent.io/blog/testing-kafka-streams/)

Here is an example:

https://github.com/openzipkin-contrib/zipkin-storage-kafka/blob/56afb2e7a0bd4381cab9c97002018d301c331b29/storage/src/test/java/zipkin2/storage/kafka/streams/TraceStorageTopologyTest.java#L186-L200

If you want to test your `func1` which accesses KafkaStreams instance, it will require an integration test. TestContainers can help to have a Kafka Cluster available for your tests https://www.testcontainers.org/modules/kafka/